# Dropdownlist using viewbag data in mvc4 using c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi i want to fill a dropdown list in my view page my code is

```
public class MemberBasicData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Mem_NA { get; set; }
    public string Mem_Occ { get; set; }
}
```

//controller

```
  public ActionResult Register()
    {
        var users = new Member().GetAllMembers();
        ViewBag.Users = users;   
        return View();
    }
```

//View

```
 @model IEnumerable<....Members.Models.MemberBasicData>
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Mem_Na, (SelectList)ViewBag.Users, "--Select Users--")
```

i want to add Mem_NA to dropdownlist, Viewbag contains all the user details. Problem is in View page. An error shows in model.Mem_Na. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: @No One:could contain a definition for Mem_NA

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please, change your code

from

```
@model IEnumerable<....Members.Models.MemberBasicData>
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Mem_Na, (SelectList)ViewBag.Users, "--Select Users--")
```

to

```
@model ....Members.Models.MemberBasicData
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id,new SelectList(ViewBag.Users,"Id","Mem_NA"), "--Select Users--")
```

It works for me everytime

Answer (score 1):

Your model is an `IEnumerable` of `MemberBasicData`, not an instance of `MemberBasicData`. This means you cannot access properties of `MemberBasicData` directly, as the property doesn't exist against an `IEnumerable`.

From what little I can see from your code I imagine you want your model to be an instance, not a list.

Answer (score 0):

Misspelling? You have spelled Mem_Na in your view and Mem_NA in your model